# jquery and ajax returns error

Tags: jquery, ajax

My ajax call in jQuery is not working. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jefffabiny/czZKM/

My page2.html file is simply:

```
<p>page 2</p>
```

Does anyone see the problem? All the error says is 'error'.

**EDIT**
My jquery is in a subfolder of my root directory. [my root folder (where my index is)] >> [my js folder (where my jquery is)]. So, the '../' syntax should be correct for going up one level in the file structure. I think, lol.

Comment: When ran in jsFiddle it shows: GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/page2.html 404 (NOT FOUND) 

What is the console output when you run this code in your project?

Comment: Did you check if the path `'../page2.html'` is correct? Can be a problem of relative/absolute path.

Comment: You can't test this code in jsFiddle, as it can't load your `page2.html`.  You need to test this on your webserver.

Comment: [Here's your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czZKM/6/) with the proper ajax call sample.  It doesn't solve your problem but helps you make sure your call is being made at least.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because page2.html cannot be found.

```
getContent('../page2.html');
```

This line is the cuplrit.

I assume that the path is incorrect.

For the jsFiddle you will need to provide an absolute path (http://www.example.com/page2.html)

Comment: my jquery is in a folder called js, which is a sub folder in my root directory. So: root (where my index.html is) > js (where my jquery is). The '../' should be correct for going up one level in the file structure, or am I wrong?

Comment: correct the jsFiddle to provide an absolute path and then we will be able to help you.

Comment: You can't load arbitrary pages with JavaScript.  You need to follow the Same-Origin Policy.  An absolute path won't work here.

Comment: @Rocket Can you explain, or point me to where I can read about the Same-Origin policy?

Answer (score 0):

Your path might not exist. Take a look in FireBug network tab or Chrome and see if you are getting a 404. Also I would recommend using the built in jQuery function that does exactly what you are looking for very concisely:

```
<p class="test"><a href="#">I will load text on click.</a></p>
<div class="contentArea">test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.contentArea').load('../page2.html');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call getContent like bellow:

```
getContent('/page2.html');
```

It will assume that the file is in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

OP: Don't get too caught up in same-origin policy and jsFiddle issues.

Check if the call is working locally.  The following code WILL work (obviously replace `C:\` with whatever your local drive or root folder is):

```
C:\test\page2.html
C:\test\subdir\test.js
C:\test\subdir\test.html
```

page2.html

```
<p>page 2 content</p>
```

test.js:

```
$.ajax({ url: '../page2.html',  
         success: function(resp) { $('body').append(resp); } 
});
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

test.html (after AJAX call):

```
<html>
<body><p>page 2 content</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The ajax call cannot refer to a relative path (i.e. '../'), it must be absolute (i.e. 'http://localhost/page2.html').